# Converting Handlebars expressing to lowercase and dashes

Tags: javascript, regex, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to reuse some of the data in my [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) template on the front end.

To do this, I need to convert one of my expressions to lowercase, and use dashes instead of space. Is this easily done?

For example, in my JSON file I have the following:

```
var items = [{
    id: '1',
    title: "Item Number One",
},

{
    id: '2',
    title: "Item Number Two",
},

];
```

And on the Handbars template on the front-end I would like to do this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="items">

    <h1>
        {{title}}
    </h1>

    <img src="{{unbound title}}.png" />

</script>
```

This will output the image page as `<img src="Item Number One.png" />` which is no good. So is there an easy way of converting this to lowercase, and remove spaces?

Comment: How does it go from `{{unbound title}}` to `Item Number One` ?

Comment: It's using [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom Handlebars Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("noSpaces", function(input) {
    var output = input.toLowerCase();
    return output.replace(" ", "");
});
```

And then call it as:

```
<img src="{{noSpaces title}}.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can map your items array and apply the template to that modified array like so:

```
var items = [

{
    id: '1',
    title: "Item Number One",
},

{
    id: '2',
    title: "Item Number Two",
},

];

items = items.map(function(el) {
    el.title = el.title.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
    return el;
});

// items = [{id:"1",title:"item-number-one"},{id:"2",title:"item-number-two"}]
```

If you need to retain the original array just assign the mapped array to a different variable.